# C# Can I use a single variable that can be one of multiple object types derived from the same abstract class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, strong-typing

I have a form that edits the properties of objects that are similar and all derived from the same abstract class.  I do not want to write separate code for each object type.  Is there a standard or, at least, easy way to do this?  I have searched around and with strongly typed (term?) variables, is there perhaps no way?

I've tried using var and object types, but in c# you cannot access the properties (or methods) that way.

The classes that inherit the abstract class are pretty similar.  Here is an example of one, which highlights the only differences:

```
{
    public class REG : Support.BaseTag
    {

        #region "Constructors"
        public Tag_REPAIR_REG() : base(){}
        public Tag_REPAIR_REG(String tagHandle) : base(tagHandle){}
        #endregion


        #region "Overrides"
        public override string TagType
        {
            get { return tagType; }
        }

        public override string TygTypeBlockName
        {
            get { return tagTypeBlockName; }
        }

        public override Dictionary<string, string> UserAttributes
        {
            get { return userAttributtes; }
        }
        #endregion


        #region "Private Variables"
        private readonly string tagType = "Regular";
        private readonly string tagTypeBlockName = "REG";
        private readonly Dictionary<string,string> userAttributtes = new Dictionary<string,string>(); //regular tag has no user atts
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Your overrides are strings or Dictionary of strings.  Why don't you have them in the base class?  What's the difference between them?

Comment: We've considered having only one class.  however, its actually another program which determines that supplies us with the object we need to manipulate, at least conceptually.  We were trying to capture those objects conceptually, and make an class for each one, as from an organizational point of view it was elegant.  But if we have to write separate code  to manipulate each type, then maybe dynamically determining the string variables may be are best choice.

Comment: Why not to add another abstract class in between REG and Support.BaseTag? And implement all base stuff in it

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I'm not sure exactly how that would be implemented.  When you say in between, how would REG access the two different abstract classes--could you explain further?